# Conditional Formatting Rules

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

having a little issue. So I want to use a conditional formatting rule in excel to highlight a cell based on another cell. I have used the simple rule below but its not working at all. To be clear I have first highlighted all of row (H) that I want formatted then the below rule is put in. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
=F1="Solutions"
```

Comment: Please post some screenshots too.

Comment: Found out what the issue was - When I hit apply rule a weird number would show up instead of F1. It would show 

        =F1048567="Solutions"

Comment: So this is a non-issue then?

Comment: Yes - but it is weird that the cell changed after hitting apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell address you use is always *relative* to the cell that is currently active.

That means, if for example you active H1:H5, and your cursor is sitting on H5, the F1 applies relative to H5. Once you save, it displays the formula relative to H1, which would be F-4 (which Excel transforms to F1048567 = Fmax - 4).

To avoid such issues, make sure that your cursor = active cell is the first one of the selected range when you start the conditional formula editing.

Also, you might want to use `=F$1="Solutions"`, the `$` results in all target cells using that column for their conditional evaluation. Otherwise, the respective reference will move along with the target cells (and I doubt all F1:5 have the text "Solutions")

Comment: Perfect response to how I am getting the issue. Thank you Aganju!